# Solo se permitan números y puntos en el elemento <input>

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando crear una reglas básicas para que los usuarios no creen datos incorrectos en ciertos campos.

Partiendo del codigo:

### HTML

```
<input id="tel_contacto" name="tel_contacto" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="9" minlength="9" style="border-radius:20px;" required="">
```

He conseguido mediante este código que solo me permita números, pero solo me permite la introduccion de un solo punto:

### HTML + JavaScript

```
<input  id="tel_contacto" name="tel_contacto" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="9" minlength="9" style="border-radius:20px;" required="" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
```

Ademas, el campo **minlength** a dejado de funcionar permitiendo la introducción de datos menores de 9 caracteres.

Comment: también podrías utilizar `<input type="number">`

Comment: Lo he estado probando pero no me convence demasiado, parece que number esta mas enfocado a un rango mas que a un dato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que la expresión que buscas es: `/^[0-9.]+$/` el signo `+` te permite una o más ocurrencias.

```js
function securePhoneNumber(el) {
  const regex = /^[0-9.]+$/
  if (!regex.test(el.value)) {
    el.value = el.value.substring(0, el.value.length - 1)
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="tel_contacto" name="tel_contacto" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="9" minlength="9" required="" oninput="securePhoneNumber(this)" placeholder="Número de teléfono">
```

Answer (score 2):

Es necesario que leas un poco de documentación para que entiendas los conceptos básicos([html5](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML)). Si le das a maxlength y minlength los mismos valores podrías tener problemas mas adelante debido a que cada navegador interpretaría esto diferente. Lo ideal es que uses expresiones regulares. En html existe un atributo llamado pattern, el mismo que te permitirá agregar validaciones a tus formularios. Te dejo un ejemplo de validación en el que solo se deben ingresar 3 caracteres alfanuméricos:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos te dejare una función muy útil que me ayudado en varias ocasiones:

```
function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
  ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {
    textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Dicha función permite aplicar cualquier filtro a un **input** tipo **texto** esta maneja tambien los eventos Copiar, Pegar, Arrastrar y Soltar entre otros eventos lo cual te permite tener un mejor control sobre el input con el filtro correspondiente.

Ahora bien el filtro que admitirá solo números enteros será:

```
setInputFilter(document.getElementById("mi_input"), function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value);
});
```

Numeros Enteros y con un limite(500):

```
/^\d*$/.test(value) && (value === "" || parseInt(value) <= 500)
```

Bien ahora para verlo en acción:

```js
function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
  ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {
    textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      }
    });
  });
}//end function setInputFilter

//aplicando el filtro
setInputFilter(document.getElementById("input"), function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" name="input">
```

Bien espero te sirva y suerte.

si deseas mas validaciones te dejare los siguientes enlaces:

[JavaScript Validacion](http://javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)

[Html numeric Input](https://github.com/lockevn/html-numeric-input)